# Why are Bomber's friends so weak?

Tags: hunter-x-hunter

Why would Bomber be hanging out with two weaklings? Neither of them even had nen power that they used.

Also, why didn't Kilua fight Bomber? It seems like his abilities would've been better to use against Bomber since he was using ranged attacks but had a good way of defending himself.

I can see why Biske didn't want to fight him but honestly, Gon seems like the weaker of him and Kilua so wouldn't it make more sense for him to fight Bomber?

Answer (score 1):

About the "weaklings": Considering how Genthru (the Bomber) wanted to heal his friends first means they're friends and not just allies. So it doesn't matter if they're weak, he wants them by his side because he trusts them.

Gon as of from the start wants the hardest challenge (Hisoka, Pitou), so it makes sense that he takes the leader. Also Genthru is at least high level which means even if Gon and Killua take him head on, he would still win. The reason Gon is the right choice is because of the plan. They need a powerful attack (Janken), enough to go through Genthru's defense. And Killua doesn't have that kind of power.